# How can I add elements to this object

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I had this structure

```
var data = 
{ 
    "people": [ 
      { "name" : "John", "id" : 1 },
      { "name" : "Marc", "id" : 2 }
    ] 
}
```

I want to add more elements to this, in JavaScript, specifically in jQuery to then send it like this

```
var dataString = JSON.stringify(data);
$.post('some.php', { data: dataString}, showResult, "text");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var data = 
{ 
    "people": [ 
      { "name" : "John", "id" : 1 },
      { "name" : "Marc", "id" : 2 }
    ] 
}
data["people"].push({"name": "foo", "id": 3});

console.log(data);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RK4bx/