# Can I add to a javascript object once its defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following javascript code:

```
var oLink = {
        title:   $link.attr('title') || '',
        row:     $link.attr('data-row') || ''
    }
```

Is it possible to add another field **once these fields have already been defined** so as to achieve:

```
var oLink = {
        viewUrl: $link.attr('data-href') || '',
        title:   $link.attr('title') || '',
        row:     $link.attr('data-row') || ''
    }
```

Comment: `oLink.viewUrl = $link.attr('data-href') || '';`

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059659/how-can-i-add-elements-to-this-object?rq=1

Comment: I recommend to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always.

There is practically never a time that this wouldn't work.

```
var myObj = { x : 0, y : 1 };
myObj.z = 2;
myObj["A"] = { x : 0 };
```

Now you've got:

```
{
    x : 0,
    y : 1,
    z : 2,
    A : { x : 0 }
}
```

Comment: That's not quite right ;) ECMAScript 5 adds [`Object.preventExtensions()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions) and [`Object.seal()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal) which prevents the addition of future properties to an object.

Comment: Yes.  And theoretically, you can freeze objects, which will prevent any modification of any properties, as well as adding setters and getters (and eventually, some full-blown low-level proxy abilities).

I am, however, hopeful that there aren't too many people who are brand-new to JS, who jump head-first into ES5/Harmony/Next/etc...